# why this jquery ajax doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, ajax

if i run this, i get the "sending" messages but "received" message doesn't show up. why? the error message is No Transport in the fail and error block.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.hotmail.com">hotmail.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").each(function (index) {
            var sUrl = 'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=' + $(this).attr('href')
            alert('sending: ' + sUrl);
            $.ajax({
                url: sUrl,
                crossDomain: true
            }).fail(function (data) {
                alert('failed: ' + data.statusText);
            }).error(function (data) {
                alert('error: ' + data.statusText);
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert('received: ' + sUrl);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

edit: the accepted answer uses $.getJSON which calls $.ajax internally. for those who may be interested in low level $.ajax, here you go.

```
$('a').each(function (index) {
    var app = 'http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/';
    var sUrl = app + '?url=' + $(this).attr('href') + '&callback=?';
    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ajax:' + data.tinyurl);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("jqXHR=" + jqXHR.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you see your request in any devtools/firebug?

Comment: Also, try to add a `.fail()` handler as well and see what it gets. If you're not getting `.done()` called, you should be getting `.fail()` called.

Comment: Add `fail` callback to see if you request is failing.

Comment: Have you tried an in-browser tool to see if the call is successful (http code = 200)? Something like Firebug/Firefox, or the dev tools in Chrome.

Comment: Heh, no nothing != nothing `:)`

Comment: http return status code is 200 when the page is ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a problem because you are making a cross domain call and not using jsonp. See the answer here for a solution to your tinyurl generation problem:

[Create TinyURL via Jquery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414145/create-tinyurl-via-jquery-ajax-call)

Using that as reference, here is your fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(index) {
        var sUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.getJSON("http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?&callback=?", {
            url: sUrl
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data.tinyurl);
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: why does it have to go through appspot.com? can't i go to tinyurl.com directly?

Comment: The appspot link is a JSONP wrapper that someone wrote to allow you to use tinyurl through AJAX. Tinyurl doesn't support AJAX requests directly so this is necessary. The answer I linked to and the other answer on this page provide some more details about the reasons you can't make a cross domain ajax call without the server supporting a JSONP response.

Answer (score 2):

The crossDomain parameter does not do what you think it does. From the JQuery docs:

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

Note that if you're requesting a URL from a different domain over AJAX, JQuery will set this to true by default - so it is unnecessary for you to set it yourself.

The reason the code isn't working is you haven't set up cross domain AJAX properly. Due to potential security vulnerabilities, browsers follow the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for AJAX requests. So the fact that you're trying to access the tinyURL API with an AJAX request will be blocked automatically by the browser. You will need to use a mechanism such as JSONP to get this to work.

[Try this blog post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/create-a-tinyurl-with-jsonp/), which has an example of using JQuery/AJAX/JSONP to get shortened URLs from the TinyURL API. It also has some background links about JSONP at the end. Note that it's a bit old, so you may need to update the syntax to the current JQuery/TinyURL API. The basic ideas behind working with JSONP are unchanged.