# Getting TinyUrl in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function ShortUrl(bigurl)
{
$.getJSON(
  "http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php",
   url: 'http://dfsghdsvfbjvjd.com',
  function(data){
   alert(data);
  });
}
```

Not Working

```
$['getJSON']('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://xxxxxxx.com/', function (a) {
                         h = a;
alert (h);

                     });
```

This Call is Also Not Working.
Tried Various calls but not getting tinyurl.

Comment: TinyURL does not support JSONP

Comment: `url: 'http://dfsghdsvfbjvjd.com'` is a syntax error.

Comment: my be due to cross site scripting policy. See this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414145/create-tinyurl-via-jquery-ajax-call][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414145/create-tinyurl-via-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 4):

The API you are using is not returning the shortened URL as JSON but as plain text. And there is no way to extract plain text data from another domain (here tinyurl) with an AJAX call. See [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If all you want to do is shorten an URL client-side, [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) has an API that supports JSONP.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?',
    {
        format: "json",
        apiKey: YOUR_API_KEY,
        login: YOUR_LOGIN,
        longUrl: "http://link.to.be/shortened"
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.url);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `$.getJSON` with this api link like: http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=google.com. Because it returns the short url as plain text.

So, I think this would be enough:

```
$.get("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=google.com", function(shorturl){
    alert(shorturl)
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: This will break if there is no [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) implementation on both the user's browser and the target domain.

Comment: I have used it billion times and no trouble. It simply requests via GET for plain text and gets the plain text result. That's it..

Comment: That is very strange. The only exception to same origin policy I heard of is for web fonts in Firefox. You may have tweaked you browser's security or there is something I definitely don't get. FYI I just tried it on the chrome console (in SO's context) and it breaks.

Comment: Indeed, when I try this, I get the browser error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."  Rather than downvote without explanation, there's your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the TinyUrl API directly in the browser would lead you to CORS issue, one of the workaround is to use cors-anywhere service. I usually use the `tinyurl-client` npm package to shorten url on the browser, here is how to use it

1. Install it in your terminal

```sh
npm install @kulkul/tinyurl-client
```

2. Use it on your javascript

```js
import shortenUrl from "@kulkul/tinyurl-client";

shortenUrl("https://kulkul.tech").then((result) => {
    console.log({ result }); // https://tinyurl.com/<slug>
});
```

P.S. I'm the creator of the npm package, if you have any issue, you can post it here https://github.com/kulkultech/tinyurl-client

Comment: You are correct regarding the CORS issue, and unfortunately, cors-anywhere has been shut down.